# 64 bit machine with WSS on it (not the MOSS)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, 64-bit, wss, web-farm

Is it possible to build a 64 bit machine and just install the free WSS and then attach it to the 32 bit Farm (where both WSS and MOSS are installed)?

If yes, can someone point me to the right article or list all the things need to be done in order to accomplish this task.

Thanks
JAF

Comment: Do you mean Sharepoint Foundation 2010? Beause this is only as 64bit available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot join a machine to farm when it runs different version SharePoint from the rest of the farm, like in your case, the machine has to run MOSS to be able to join MOSS farm. WSS alone will not do.

Comment: Thanks Vladi. I am talking about SP 2007 just different CPU type.

Comment: In that case i believe that we have done it before and it worked